# Randomize HTML5 Video poster image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, video

I've made a HTML5 video player and I'd like to force the poster image to show up for at least 4 seconds before the video plays. I'd also like to randomize the images that show up.

I've tried to use PHP to look in side the images folder and randomize before image 1 to 3. However, I can't get the image to show up at all and I can't get it to randomize. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="vidWrap">

<video autoplay id="movingAlphaVid" style="display: none;"                                                                

preload="auto" poster="/images/image_<?php $random = rand(1,3); echo   $random; ?>.png" >
```

Comment: Where is the source code / attempt(s)? Please update your question and include the relevant source code.

Comment: Try to use `<?php echo rand(1,3); ?>` directly.

Comment: I just did as you suggested. However, I can't tell if its working or not. I need somehow to force the image to show up for a few seconds prior to the video playing. My video plays automatically every time. I deleted autoplay but that didn't do the trick either.

Comment: Where is `src` set for `<video>` element?

Comment: I didn't copy the src in my question. I'm not having any issues with the src. It's the poster image that I'm trying to adjust.

Comment: Is `.` missing before `<?php`?

Comment: No, why would there be a . there? the . is at the end .png

Answer (score 0):

This code will work

```
<video autoplay id="movingAlphaVid" 
    controls="controls" src="your_video_file.ext" preload="auto"  
    poster="/images/image_<?php $random = rand(1,3); echo $random; ?>.png" >
```

Also check the `video` tag documentation at [HTML Video Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)